# Why do both ways of accesing module functions exist in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
module A
  def self.func
    puts "func"
  end
end

>> A.func
func
>> A::func
func
```

Why do both `.` and `::` exist? Why not only `.`?

Answer (score 3):

The scope resolution operator (`::`) can resolve constants, instance methods, and class methods, so we can use that operator for essentially any method as long as we are looking in the right place.

Additionally, since the method "func" is defined as a class method of module A (by `self.func`, analogous to a "static" method) it belongs directly to the module (which is itself an object) so it can be called with the dot operator with the module as the receiver.  Note that instances of module A do not have any visibility to "func", since it is a class method:

```
aye = Object.new.extend(A)
aye::func # raises NoMethodError
aye.func  # raises NoMethodError
```

If the method was defined as an instance method then it could only be called with the dot operator on instances of the module.

```
module B
  def func2
    puts "OK!"
  end
end
B::func2 # raises NoMethodError
B.func2  # raises NoMethodError
bee = Object.new.extend(B)
bee::func2 # "OK!"
bee.func2  # "OK!"
```

Comment: @RHSeeger, Because Ruby is a postmodern language: There doesn't have to be only one way to do a things (and it may even be considered better to have more than one).  A minimalist language core, as in C, Java, &c., is not really in play in Ruby.

Comment: @Wayne: Deleted my comment because I misread and misrepresented what the actual question was. I read it as "what is the difference" when the real question was "why have both, since they are the same thing". While I'm not sure maerics' answer answers this clearly enough, my comment isn't really appropriate.

Comment: As a random tidbit, I'm firmly of the opinion that "postmodern" is a bad way to label a programming language. I'd call Ruby a modern programming language, meaning that it takes advantage of many of the developments in programming language design to create something that is both easy to use and expressive (so easy to maintain). That being said, there's nothing really revolutionary about Ruby. I love the language and think it's a great combination of features from other languages, but I can't think of anything it brought to the table that was a leap from previous languages.

Comment: @RHSeeger, I'm using postmodern in the sense that Larry Wall (Perl) uses it here: http://www.perl.com/pub/1999/03/pm.html .  As I understand Larry, the essence of a postmodern language is _not_ that it has invented anything new, but simply that it breaks from those attributes common in modernist languages (a minimalist core, one best way to do a thing, resistance to metaprogramming, fidelity to the machine's needs rater than the programmer's, &c.).  Ruby indeed breaks from all of those conventions; in that sense, it is thoroughly postmodern.